# Navigate between views in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am about to make a simple application to iOS in Xamarin studio for mac. My current problem is the fact that I want to be sent from one view to another. Currently, I have three views (They use the navigation controller with topbar):

Homescreen 
Accommodations Screen 
Index Screen 
These works that navigate between, "Home Screen" contains two buttons that lead to the two other views (Accommodations Screen, Screen Records). But if I create a third view, which is single. For example, the View "Dashboard Screen".

I want to be able to "link" "Dashboard Screen" from the "Facility Screen. How do I then do?, I tested the code below:

```
btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
    DashboardScreen dashboardscreen = new DashboardScreen();
    NavigationController.PushViewController (dashboardscreen, false);
};
```

But then I get an error, Xamarin Studio opens the file "Main.cs" and mark the line:

```
UIApplication.Main (args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

I see that there is a "balloon" at that line that says:

```
NSInvalidArgymentException Reason: [LoginScreen btn] unrexognized selector sent to instance. 0x12628eb0
```

How could I correctly make the "btn" change view to "DashboardScreen" from "LoginScreen"?

Comment: Are you creating your views in code, or are you using the Interface Designer tool to create them?

Comment: @Jason Interface Designer in Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the error is on your DashboardScreen page and not with navigating to it. What if you set it as the RootViewController and load into that page to make sure that it renders it correctly.

Comment: No errors found, did what you said and successfully got my screen to render.

Comment: Try deleting the button, saving, then recreating it. Maybe something got hosed between Xcode and MT during synchronization.